# Can't access on server after used ufw and forgot to allow port 22 to SSH

Tags: ssh, server, linode, ufw

I have used UFW on my server, and I forgot to allow port 22 to ssh. Now I can not access on the server. I using hosting by Linode. Please give me a solution, I can not find anything to open port 22, because I can not access it.

ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a support ticket on Linode.

What they would tell you though is to access your Linode "out-of-band" with the Linode Shell a.k.a. LiSH. THey have a [Linode Doc](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/using-the-linode-shell-lish/).

Comment: There is 2 solutions.
1) Login via LiSH using web interface
2) Reset linode

Answer (score 0):

Use a VNC client and you would be able to log in without ssh. I was able to do that when I ran into the same problem (getting ufw to open port 22 but instead locking myself out) via my VPS settings page located in the website of the VPS provider.